# Masking in pytorch TransformerEncoder

Tags: pytorch, masking, transformer-model

I am wondering how you can make TransformerEncoder predict mask values in the training session. Currenlty what I am doing is that the parts I am "masking" in the input vector is to change their value with 0.0 and then pass the new vector into the model. But I think this is not working properly and that the model doesn't recognize that this 0.0 is in fact a mask value to predict but rather that this is just the input vector value.

I tried just changing the value to 0.0

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to do BERT style input masking. To do this, you should replace the masked input token with a special `[MASK]` token that the model learns.